# Run-time error: Debug Assertion Failed when using Classes

Tags: debugging, c++, runtime-error

I am writing code for an assignment in my college C++ class, the program is meant to create a dynamically allocated array using a class. I am getting a debug assertion failed error when my objects go out of scope, because I am double deleting the pointer to the newly created array. I have no idea where this happens because I only use delete[] twice in the entire class. Here is my source:
    #include

```
using namespace std;

//classes
class IntArray {
private:
int * begin;
int arrSize;

//returns true if n is a valid index inside the array
bool inBounds(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n >= arrSize) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public:
//default constructor
IntArray() {
    begin = new int[1];
    begin[0] = 0;
    arrSize = 1;
}

//call constructor
IntArray(int n) {
    arrSize = n;
    begin = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        begin[i] = 0;
    }

}

//copy constructor
IntArray(IntArray * in) {
    arrSize = in->size();
    begin = new int[arrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        begin[i] = in->begin[i];
    }
}

//call constructor for arrays
IntArray(int in[],int s) {
    arrSize = s;
    begin = new int[arrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        begin[i] = in[i];
    }
}

//method functions

//returns the size of the array
int size() {
    return arrSize;
}

//returns the value of the element at position n
int get(int n) {
    if (inBounds(n)) {
        return begin[n];
    }

    cout << "Error: Invalid bound entered, returning value at index 0" << endl;
    return begin[0];
}

//function that sets the value at position n to the value of input
void put(int n, int input) {
    if (inBounds(n)) {
        begin[n] = input;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error: invalid bound entered, no value changed" << endl;
    }
}

//overloaded operators

//sets the value at the position n to input value
int & operator[](int n) {
    if (inBounds(n)) {
        return begin[n];
    }
    cout << "Error: invalid bound entered, returning index 0" << endl;
    return begin[0];
}

//operator = allows copying of one IntArray to another
IntArray & operator=(IntArray source) {
    arrSize = source.size();
    delete[] begin;
    begin = 0;

    begin = new int[arrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
        begin[i] = source[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

//destructor
~IntArray() {
    //deallocate memory used by array
    if (begin != 0) {
        delete[] begin;
    }
}


};

int main() {
IntArray arr1(10);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr1[i] = 11 * i;
    cout << arr1[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << arr1.get(i) << " ";
}
cout << endl;

arr1.put(6, 16);
arr1.put(4, 10);

IntArray arr2(arr1);

IntArray arr3 = arr1;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << arr3.get(i) << " ";
}
cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << arr2.get(i) << " ";
}
cout << endl;


system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

And a screenshot of the exact error:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?  Put breakpoints on the two places you call `delete` and debug.

Comment: Just as a note, your copy constructor is not [defined correctly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: @heavyd I have run it through the debugger, the problem arises when the destructor is called and attempts to delete an already deleted dynamically allocated array. And as for the copy constructor, when I try to use const IntArray &, it won't let me use pointer notation or another other notation that I know how to use.

Comment: When you have a reference to an object (ie. `const IntArray &`) you can just use the dot notation.  The reason I mention that the copy constructor is wrong, is that when you're constructing `arr2` and `arr3`, you're not actually calling the constructor you think you are (put a breakpoint there, you'll see its never hit).

Comment: I try using dot notation and it says 'object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function object type is: const IntArray'

Comment: Yes.. which line gives you that error?  Remember, when a reference comes in as `const` you're not allowed to modify it or call any functions that might modify it (class member functions can declare that they will not make any modifications using the `const` keyword).

Comment: I edited line 40, I changed it to     arrSize = in.size(); the member function does not and can not modify that data. I am unsure how I would edit it to make that more clear to the compiler.

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/

Comment: Alright, that worked beautifully. It also seems to have fixed my debug assertion failed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @heavyd I realized that the error arose from an improper construction of the class due to a logic error in my class definition. The problem was in the way I was copying data to the new class (improperly) and the way that my copy constructor worked, as well as the return type of one of my member functions.